# Rails 6 and controller#render changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

In Rails <6 we were able to call:

```
render 'iframe', layout: false
```

But now this results in:

```
  ActionView::Template::Error:
       wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
```

How to properly address this in Rails 6?

Comment: You missed a comma there. `render 'iframe', layout: false`

Comment: @SebastianPalma thanks for noticing. It was a typo in the question and I fixed it but I am still getting this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using example I provided is valid in Rails 6.

Problem was there due to not yet merged in changes for `rspec-rails` gem:

This branch fixed the issue:

```
gem 'rspec-rails', git: 'https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails', branch: '4-0-dev'
```

Credits: http://jessehouse.com/blog/2019/06/19/actionview-template-error-wrong-number-of-arguments-given-2/

Answer (score 3):

Try using `template` as outlined [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render)

```
render template: 'iframe', layout: false
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually the branch is now renamed: `4-0-maintenance`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the pre-release branch:

`gem 'rspec-rails', '4.0.0.beta3'`

Reference: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/2177